Use 12 volt DC power instead of a 12 volt battery
I have a 5 kW inverter, and it works using a 12 V DC battery. I am looking for options where I can use a 12 V DC current to connect with the 5 kW inverter. By doing so, will I draw less current if I connect a 1.5 ton air conditioner to the inverter compared to using the air conditioner in AC 220 V? Also how many ampere is required to switch on the 5 kW inverter considering 12 V DC input?


Why do you expect any difference in current drawn when running on mains or on the inverter output - assuming the inverter matches the mains voltage? 2. Are you familiar with the power equation, $ P = VI $?


If you have AC available to power your DC power supply, why do you need an inverter for your AC load?

If your 5000 W invertor is 90% efficient, then for a 5000 W output it needs a 5600 W input.  At 12 V, that is 467 amps.  That's a lot.  At that current level, cables and connectors (and a 6 kW 12 Vdc source) will be significant problems.
No combination of power sources and technologies will be more efficient than running the AC directly off the mains it was designed for.  At those power levels, expect to lose 10% - 20% of your energy to heat in each conversion stage.

Be prepared for a fire. 5 kW is well beyond 12-volt applications, and there is no such thing as a 12-volt 500 amp DC power Supply. They would be too dangerous and expensive to make. The cable size required to handle 500 amps is as large as your wrist. Consider voltage drops and the cable getting larger to limit losses. Lastly, if any connections get the slightest bit loose or corrosion, you have a fire on your hands hot enough to melt and spew molten copper.
12-volt systems are for low-powered systems tailored to vehicle gizmos. Anything more than 600 to 700 watts is beyond 12-volt capability. Any higher, you risk fire and very high cable power losses.
To make 5000-watt inverters feasible and safe, you need a minimum of 48 to 60 volts DC. Commercial and industrial inverters run on 100 to 600-volt DC  with battery backup.
The automotive industry is about to move away from 12-volt systems. The electrical demands exceed 12-volt capabilities. Too many fires were caused by high-power devices like A/V equipment, heated seats, Nav/Com, and all the other toys. The move is toward 24—and 36-volt battery systems. They will save weight and space in vehicles.
I have seen many solar users trying to use 12-volt systems. They do so because they are ignorant. They do not understand the limitations and dangers until it bites them in the wallet and butt. I have seen many burned-up cables/connectors/equipment. They used anywhere from 2000 to 5000-watt inverters using 4 or 6 AWG cables between the battery and inverter. To handle the current, 500 amps require 750 MCM and large connectors with much surface area. They learned an expensive lesson.
Carry on.
